# Angular 4/5: Field is invalid if untouched or browser autofilled

Tags: angular, validation

Take the following form as an example:

```
<form [formGroup]="MyGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(MyGroup)">
   <input type="email" value="{{data.email}}" formControlName="email">
</form>

...

MyGroup = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email
    ]),
...

onSubmit(form) {
   console.log(form.controls['email'].hasError('required'));
}
```

This will always trigger an `invalid` validation result if form is submitted without modifying the `email` field.

Same goes if the browser autofills the form data.

My question is: Is there a way to re-validate the FormGroup fields regardless of the `untouched` state?

Comment: if it is untouched why will you revalidate ?

Comment: Because the form can be tampered with invalid data without actually typing in the email value upon loading. 

BTW, I am only using "email" as an example. The actual fields I am working on are much more sensitive than that.

Comment: i still dnt understand you , you want the form to validate only on invalidated fields or what

Comment: Sorry if I am not explaining it well enough.  

As you can see, the field is autofilled with a value on load and there is no way to know if the value is valid or not (or if the field value is modified in transit or by modifying the value of the field on the browser console.) 

The problem is, the form will not submit because ```hasError``` will always return ```true``` if the field is not modified manually by the user.

Comment: i am not sure if i am getting you but are looking for validation onBlur events

Comment: I think the issue is your code is filling the form with a value, and the email is a required field. If you want to run the validation you assigned on the form, you can make all field as touched.

Comment: Could `updateValueAndValidity()` do it?

Comment: @Ringo Yes. That was what I wanted to know: how to mark fields as touched so it can go to proper validation.

Comment: @DeborahK Something like this?: ```MyGoup.updateValueAndValidity()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED:

After playing around with the demo, looks like if you pass in the value on to the form control, the validation work as intended.

```
this.MyGroup = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(this.data.email, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email
      ]
      )
    })
```

See demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7r7s8k?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, didn't work. Errors still persist.

Comment: Yes. I even confirmed that the field changed to ```touched:true``` and it was indeed changed but ```hasError('required')``` still returned ```true```. Looks like Angular 4/5 treats untouched fields as ```null```

Comment: Ah my bad, I thought I solved this before. Let me double check later

Comment: @JhourladEstrella updated my answer with demo, hope it fix your issue

Comment: OMG! It works! I actually got it working a while ago using ```MyGroup.controls['email'].setValue("me@mydomain.com")``` but yours is more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your input **name** attribute.
See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp

> Definition and Usage
>   The name attribute specifies the name of an  element.
>
> The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.
>
> Note: **Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form**.

A simple test - write yourself a test validator, you'll see that it never gets called on autofill unless you have the name attribute set to something.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  projectStatus = ['Stable', 'Critical', 'Finished'];

  builderForm = this.builder.group({
    email: ['',
      [Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
        TestComponent.emailTestValidator()]],
  });

  static emailTestValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      console.log('Email Test Validator Hit');
      return null;
    };
  }
```

Template:

```
<label class="as7-label">
  Email:
  <input type="email"
         name="as7email"
         placeholder="john@doe.com"
         formControlName="email">
</label>
```

If you skip the name attribute the validator never gets hit